# For Loop Inside Angular Subscribe taking too long in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, subscribe

I have created a chat application in Ionic4 with firebase as backend. And I have given the option to create groups. So my problem is when i am trying to create a new group, my app crashes due to loading all users inside the "Create New Group" page. Here is my code:

**new-group.page.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.group = {
      img: "./assets/img/default-group.png"
    };
    this.searchFriend = "";

    this.getData.getCurrentUser().snapshotChanges().subscribe(async (accountRes: any) => {
      let account: any = { $key: accountRes.key, ...accountRes.payload.val() };
      if (!this.groupMembers) {
        this.groupMembers = [account];
      }
    });

    this.getData.getUsers().snapshotChanges().subscribe(async (usersRes) => {
      console.log("Inside Second Subscribe");
      let c: any = [];
      c = usersRes.map(c => ({ key: c.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
      if (c.length > 0) {
        //this loops forever not just once
        for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
          if (c[i].uid != this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid) {
            let friend = { $key: c[i].uid, ...c[i] };
            console.log("Inside For: " + i);
            this.addOrUpdateFriend(friend);
            //this.friends.push(friend);
          }
        }
      } else {
        this.friends = [];
      }
    });
  }
```

So for now I have 150 users and for each user, the for loop inside my second subscribe loops forever. Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can you share the error with us ?!

Comment: @TawfiekKhalaf: I don't get any error but if I do console log, the for loop inside nested subscribe just keep executing forever with no outcome. On device, in iOS, the "Create new group" modal page goes white after few second and take me to its parent "Messages" page.

Comment: Also, this happened when I have like more users. Initially when I tested with 10 users, it worked perfectly. But as the user list jumped to more than 100, it is not working.

Comment: interested ... 
are you sure that this log appears just ones ?!
`console.log("Kartik Second Subscribe");`

Comment: The log console.log("Kartik Second Subscribe"); keep on appearing not just once.

Comment: For example, if in the for loop inside nested subscribe, if I limit the "i" value to 20 or 30, then I am able to successfully load the data.

Comment: This is how my log gets printed: Kartik Second Subscribe              new-group.page.ts:63
128 Kartik Second Subscribe       new-group.page.ts:63

Comment: That means that observable resolved  Frequently and the component  trying to re-render the view every time, that's why it  hangup and can not make a  certain outcome, I am not sure how `snapshotChanges()` works but you have to track it's behavior and stop the observable propagation after one time